# compare two dataframes and get nearest matching dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, compare

have two dataframes with columns

df1

```
name    cell     marks  

tom      2       21862
```

df2

```
name    cell    marks     passwd

tom      2       11111      2548

matt     2       158416      2483
         2       21862      26846
```

How to compare df2 with df1 and get nearest matched data frames

expected_output:

df2

```
name    cell    marks     passwd

tom      2       11111      2548
         2       21862      26846
```

tried  `merge` but data is dynamic.  On one case `name` might change and in another case `marks` might change

Comment: It looks like you would need [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: but there is no specific column to keep constant in both dataframes for merge

Comment: Why not ``name`` & ``cell``, perform a inner merge.

Comment: in another case  marks and cell are matched. the method you told will not worrk

Comment: Have a look at merge_asof https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
dict1 = {'name': ['tom'], 'cell': [2], 'marks': [21862]}
dict2 = {'name': ['tom', 'matt'], 'cell': [2, 2],
         'marks': [21862, 158416], 'passwd': [2548, 2483]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)

compare = df2.isin(df1)
df2 = df2.iloc[df2.where(compare).dropna(how='all').index]
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
  name  cell  marks  passwd
0  tom     2  21862    2548
```

Comment: Updated question , you answer will not work in this scenario .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.merge` with the option `indicator=True`, filtering the result for `'both'`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['tom', 2, 11111]], columns=["name", "cell", "marks"])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['tom', 2, 11111, 2548],
                    ['matt', 2, 158416, 2483]
                    ], columns=["name", "cell", "marks", "passwd"])


def compare_dataframes(df1, df2):
    """Find rows which are similar between two DataFrames."""
    comparison_df = df1.merge(df2,
                              indicator=True,
                              how='outer')
    return comparison_df[comparison_df['_merge'] == 'both'].drop(columns=["_merge"])


print(compare_dataframes(df1, df2))
```

Returns:

```
  name  cell  marks  passwd
0  tom     2  11111    2548
```

Comment: Updated question , you answer will not work in this scenario .